# Why is this background scipt not being loaded in my firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a firefox extension that has a background script but no matter what i can not get the background script to load.

When i load the extension i get a `Loading failed for the <script> with source “moz-extension://../assets/js/background.js”.` Even though i have all the files in the correct place.

Manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Background Scripts",
    "description": "Test Background Scripts",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["assets/js/background.js"]
    },  
    "version": "0.1"
}
```

The background.js file is just `console.log("Test")`

And the file structure is correct in the actual folder structure in the extension but no matter what i do i can not get the background.js file to load

**Things I Have Tried**

Restarted My Pc

Made A New Dev Profile

Disabled ALL Extension

And Making A Whole New Extension

Comment: **"When i load the extension"** What method are you using for that?

**"i have all the files in the correct place"** what does your folder structure look like exactly?

Comment: I have fixed the Issue. But i was using the load Temporary Add-on. I dont know why it wasnt working but my Firefox updated and it fixed the issue. So i would assume it was a Firefox issue